# How do I shift the contents of an array a la Super 2048?

Tags: java

More specifically, how do I shift the contents of an array like this:

> [2 0 2 8]

Into something like this:

> [0 0 4 8]

Edit:
By shifting, I mean like a game of [Super 2048](http://2048game.com/). Think of this array as one row in a 4x4 game. When I enter the command to 'shift right', the left number would look for the number equal to it, like element 0 being equal to element 2. The number in element 0 then become 0 and the one in element 2 would then add up to 4. If the number fails to find an equal number, it stops to the left of the different number.

I tried manipulating the array's elements directly like the code below, but I had no success.

```
for(int col = dimension-2; col >= 0; col--)
    {
        for(int tgtCol = col+1; tgtCol < dimension; tgtCol++)
        {
            if(initialState[tgtCol] == initialState[col])
            {
                initialState[tgtCol] += initialState[col];
                initialState[col] = 0;
            }
            /*if(initialState[tgtCol] == 0 && InitialState[col] != 0)
            {
                initialState[tgtCol] = initialState[col];
                initialState[col] = 0;
            }
            Code for later implementation
            */
            else
            {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shifting how? What's the logic behind that shift?

Comment: Are you working with 1D or 2D array?

Comment: I'm working with a 2D array, actually.

Comment: Work in smaller steps. First create a method to "shift" just on number in one direction, and make it work. Then make a method which uses this method to "shift" entire row, and make it work. Then make a 3rd method which uses the 2nd method to shift all rows. Then you can duplicate this code four times to get all four directions, and make it work. Now you have a working program! Then if you want to learn real programming, refactor the duplicate code out, so that same code can shift in any direction :)

Answer (score 0):

This'll work for you,

```
    int[] targetState = new int[dimension];
    int tCol = dimension - 1;

    for (int i = dimension - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (initialState[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        } else {
            if ((targetState[tCol] == initialState[i])) {
                targetState[tCol] += initialState[i];
                tCol--;
            } else if (targetState[tCol] == 0){
                targetState[tCol] = initialState[i];
            } else {
                targetState[--tCol] = initialState[i];
            }
        }
    }
    initialState = targetState;
```

i think inplace shifting is computationally very expensive aproach.